# Closing a Trigger.io forge mobile app via javascript (Android / iOS) - in order to apply Reload

Tags: reload, trigger.io, forge

Is it possible to ask a Trigger.io Forge mobile app to close itself through the forge JS api?

We're seeing users having problems with reloads:
We pop up a message when a reload is available, but it's difficult for us to explain that they have to

1. come out of the app
2. wait an unknown amount of time (for the reload update to download)
3. launch the app again

People either don't understand, or the force-quit the app meaning the reload doesn't download, or they come out and go straight back in before it's downloaded - and then see our 'reload' popup message immediately again.

I wondered if we could close the app for them if this would smooth things out a bit. Unless people have better suggestions for this user flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you listening for the [updateReady](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/reload.html#updateready-addlistener) events to pop up your message? If so, the Reload update has actually already been downloaded and is ready to go: all the user needs to do at that point is switch away from the app and back again; no delay required.

The only way to programmatically close a Trigger.io is in the [backPressed](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/event.html#backpressed-addlistener) event listener, which won't be of use to you in this situation.

Comment: Cheers James, have changed my code to listen for the updateReady event now - will see how this goes. Was previously using the updateAvailable function.